# Access variables from BE that are not in DOM

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Is it possible to access variables from the backend that do not display in the DOM? I'm passing a variable from backend but it is not displaying in the browser console, so can I still access in thymeleaf like this?

What makes a variable global from backend?

```
model.addAttribute(I_COME_FROM_BACKEND)

<div th:if="{I_COME_FROM_BACKEND != null}"> I'm here </div>
```

Comment: Sure, you can do that.  Did you try and it and didn't work? What's the problem?

Comment: I never do BE stuff so seeing it not come through browser I was worried. Yet to test